# .error() function alternative on jquery 3.x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I update my Jquery library from 2.x to 3.x and I found that the `$(...).error(*callback function*)` doesn't exists anymore.

I use this function to verify if a image was load successfully or not and act properly to each case.

Follows a piece of my code:

```
$(img).error(function () {
  countErrors++;
  $(img).attr("src", UIImages.prototype.getErrorUrlImage(source));
  UIImages.prototype.stopImageLoader(element, velocity.timeAnimations);
  UIImages.prototype.showOrElemImage(source, element, velocity.timeAnimations, 
                                     UIImages.prototype.getOpacity(source));
  if (countErrors == 3)
    $(img).off("error");
  callbackError && callbackError();
});
```

Thank you

Comment: `.on("error", function() {})`

Comment: `$(img).on('error', function() {...`

Comment: Read the upgrade guides when you have issues: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed

Comment: @epascarello so, the shortcut for the .on("error", function() {}) does not exists anymore ?

Comment: Read the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advices made on the question comments, I read the [jquery upgrade guides](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed) and they said:

> **Breaking change: .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed**
>
> These methods **are shortcuts for event operations**, but **had several API
>   limitations**. The event .load() method conflicted with the ajax .load()
>   method. The .error() method could not be used with window.onerror
>   because of the way the DOM method is defined. If you need to attach
>   events by these names, use the .on() method, e.g. **change
>   $("img").load(fn) to $("img").on("load", fn)**

So, follows the solution for my case:

```
$(img).on('error', function () {
  countErrors++;
  $(img).attr("src", UIImages.prototype.getErrorUrlImage(source));
  UIImages.prototype.stopImageLoader(element, velocity.timeAnimations);
  UIImages.prototype.showOrElemImage(source, element, velocity.timeAnimations, 
                                     UIImages.prototype.getOpacity(source));
  if (countErrors == 3)
    $(img).off("error");
  callbackError && callbackError();
});
```